# How to we go inside of App from Gmail link in swift

Tags: ios, swift, email, deep-linking

I want to go inside of the app for particular Controller by using of Deeplinking.

I write the following code in my AppDelegate file but it don't call that method, even also but it go to every time home page only.

```
extension AppDelegate{
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

        print("url \(url)")
        print("url host :\(url.host!)")
        print("url path :\(url.path)")


        let urlPath : String = url.path as String
        let urlHost : String = url.host as! String
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        //PickuppageControllerDeeplinking://host/inner

        if(urlHost != "mail.google.com")
        {
            print("Host is not correct")
            return false
        }

        if(urlPath == "/inner"){

            let innerPage: PickupsPageController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PickupsPageController") as! PickupsPageController
            self.window?.rootViewController = innerPage
        } else if (urlPath == "/about"){

        }
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: may be your `urlHost` not contains the "mail.google.com" and it will return form that.

Comment: No I already hit that url from gmail only and first of all compiler don't come inside of the that function.

Comment: Even it don't print the url also

Comment: Have you registered the `URL Scheme` that you're expecting to open the app?

Comment: try deeplinking

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement URL Schemes for this. Refer this [link for documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app)

You need to do two things

1. Register URL Scheme in your app
2. Handle the incoming url in App delegate Method

```swift
application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL,
                  options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:] ) -> Bool
```